# HTTPS “proper/classic” proxy

Tags: linux, open-source, proxy, https

I have two machines, let’s call them `client.example.com` and `server.example.com`, which run software that speaks disjunct SSL (versions, ciphersuites, anything). I need the client to access servers via HTTPS.

My idea is to install a classic proxy server on a third machine `debian.example.com` which speaks all SSL variants understood by the other machines, and then `export https_proxy=https://user:pass@debian.example.com:port` on the client.

This means we’re going to have two distinct HTTPS connections, one from `client` to `debian` (using a proper SSL certificate) and one from `debian` to `server`. The content is almost the same, but I cannot use a double `stunnel` solution like with imaps because `server` is not static; it needs to be a regular HTTP proxy protocol. (Consider only HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 as relevant for this question.)

I’m in need of a proxy server to use. I *think* squid can be used to do that, but anything involving that beast requires a day or multiple days to set up, so I’m looking for a simpler alternative, especially as I require no caching, filtering, not even adding headers.

So far, I’ve found that `tinyproxy` and `ffproxy` both claim to “support” HTTPS, but they neither support being connected to with https, nor actually connecting with https — they merely support the CONNECT method. Useless.

I also don’t want mitmproxy. The machines are on distinct networks, so I cannot use a transparent proxy setup, and I *am* able to obtain a proper external SSL certificate (from Letsencrtpy) for the proxy host.

The proxy uplink is just HTTPS again, no other proxy.

Comment: If you just want to make old servers provide latest TLS versions and ciphers I would install nginx as TLS terminator locally on each server, change the old server to run on a localhost interface only without TLS and then forward the TLS terminated connection from nginx to the original server. Trying to get multiple servers at once through one proxy and that's manually the proxy on client side is complex and does not scale well.

Comment: A bit more detail about the scenario @Robert: the servers in question are not under my control, and the client is the one that has the older TLS version or ciphersuites, and this can only be changed long-term.